# How to make a particle system where particles don't emit light?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, particles

How can I make a particle system where particles don't emit light ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Particle systems don't emit light by default, only if you add an emission material to it.

That looks like a *Halo* particle system, which renders as "blurred dots" in Blender internal.

Try disabling the *Halo* option under the *Properties Editor > Particles > Render > Halo* to something else like an object or group.

Alternatively add a new material to the object, set it to *Halo* type and assign it to the Particle System under *Properties Editor > Particles > Render > Material* menu. Control it's settings to match whatever effect you desire.